# useEffect Infinito

Tags: react, axios, react-hooks

gostaria de uma ajuda quanto ao uso do useEffect e axios. Atualmente, tenho o seguinte cenário em um projeto:
Tenho um hook de estado setando uma variável unidade, essa tem seu estado alterado quando recebe o fetch de uma requisição get do axios. Até aqui okay, tudo certo. Porém, após essa requisição, eu realizo outras requisições com base em um array retornado dentro do fetch anterior (ou seja, o novo estado de unidade, que é um objeto, tem um array, e este array é usado como parâmetro para outras requisições).
Essas requisições são realizadas, e tenho meus dados retornados e setado em um outro state (caracteristicas), porém essas requisições, ficam sendo efetuadas sem parar, pois estou passando a o novo state dentro do useEffect para que ele rode até esse state ser alterado, poré as requisições nao param e ficam rodando infinitamente.

Código das requisicoes:

```
const idUnidade = useLocation().state.idUnidade;

  const [unidade, setUnidade] = useState();
  const [caracteristicas, setCaracteristicas] = useState([]);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [isCarcLoaded, setIsCarcLoaded] = useState(false);
  
  const getUnidade = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios("urlRequest"+idUnidade);
    setUnidade({
      "title": data.title.rendered,
      "local": data.acf.local,
      "mainImage": data.acf.mainImage,
      "description": data.acf.unidadeDescription,
      "caracteristicas": data.acf.caracteristicas
    });

    getCaracteristicas(data.acf.caracteristicas);
    if(isCarcLoaded){
      setIsLoaded(true);
      return false;
    }
  };

  const getCaracteristicas = (arrayC) => {
    let promiseArray = arrayC.map((id) => { return axios.get('urlRquest'+id)});
    axios.all(promiseArray)
    .then(axios.spread((...res) => {
      let temp = res.map((element) => {
        return(
          {
            "id": element.data.id,
            "title": element.data.title.rendered,
            "icon": element.data.acf.servicoIcone
          }
        )
      });
      setCaracteristicas(temp);
      setIsCarcLoaded(true);
    }))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUnidade();
  }, [...caracteristicas]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Seu estado **"caracteristicas"** somente é alterado após a execução do **"getUnidade"**, toda vez que chega na função **"getCaracteristicas"**, o seu estado **"caracteristica"** irá mudar, e isso vai causar o efeito colateral de novo (vai chamar a função **"getUnidade"** novamente), já que essa é a condição de execução do useEffect. (Esse pode ser o causador desse Loop que citou)

Dica de Solução:

Assumindo que o caracteristicas somente muda após a função "getCaracteristicas", então não haveria motivo desse estar no array de dependência.

Porém o "getUnidades" , a função que você chama no useEffect, ela "deve" estar no array de dependências, já que dentro dela há alteração de estado. Porém para isso você vai ter de declarar ela com o *useCallback*, pra evitar outro Loop. *(Ou implementar a função getUnidades dentro do proprio useEffect)*

Note que o "getUnidades" não é obrigatorio de estar no array de dependencia, mas por convensão seria o **ideal** de acordo com as recomendações do proprio React, já que esse trabalha diretamente com um estado. Porém não haverá erro se você não colocar ele lá, ele apenas irá executar na primeira renderização. (O que pode ocorrer são inconsistencias futuras).

[Dependência no useEffect](https://medium.com/bitsrc/understanding-dependencies-in-useeffect-7afd4df37c96)

Comment: Mas e ai, qual a solução?

Comment: @AugustoVasques depende, nesse caso dele não está claro se ele PRECISA monitorar toda mudança do "caracteristicas". Se não for necessário, basta retirar do array de dependencia. Porém nesse caso do exemplo, a função "getUnidades" pode "precisar" ser colocada como dependência. (Editei a resposta com essa info)